# How can I compare same field in 2 different tables when it match or likes?

Tags: ms-access, compare

I need to compare 2 tables (the field is code) and create a third when name match or likes (with results from each table).

table1: name surname **code** age

table2: address city **code**

I need as results a new table with code from table1 and table2 to see the difference.

Each field are text like a345694s3.

Comment: Can you explain some more about what `code` represents and how the tables are related? Why are you trying to compare the two sets of values? What accuracy do you need? How 'like' do they need to be? Should we match from the start of the string or for any part of the string? How do you know which two rows in each table to compare? Apart from the code column they are unrelated tables, to be related table1.code = table2.code which requires exact match.

Comment: Hi! I need to see if in table2 the code is cutted (is unique code) due to massive import from a wrong formatted xls (so for example it delete the first 0 cause it think is a numeric field). So i need that must matches 10 letters (any part of the string) . The table are not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.iduser, a.idaccount, u.usercode_user, a.usercode_accounts
FROM users AS u, accounts AS a
WHERE (((a.usercode_accounts) Like "*" & [u].[usercode_user] & "*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but you can try with where condition .. 
ex:
 `select * from tab1 t1, tab2 t2 where 't1.code'='t2.code'`

If you get the result for the above code then make it as a subquery!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to see which codes are in table1 versus table2, try a FULL OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT t1.code AS T1, t2.code as T2
FROM   table1 t1
FULL   OUTER JOIN table t2
       ON t1.code = t2.code
```

Results:

```
T1     T2
====   ====
A      NULL  --'A' is in table1 but not table2
NULL   B     --'B' is in table2 but not table1
C      C     --'C' is in both tables
```

**EDIT**

As FULL OUTER JOIN is unavailable in MS Access, you can use INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, and RIGHT OUTER JOIN to achieve the same thing as discussed [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm).

Comment: No form of JOIN in Jet/ACE SQL requires the OUTER keyword. You have INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, and including OUTER has no effect on the execution -- it just makes the SQL more verbose, and as soon as you save the query, Jet/ACE strips out the OUTER. So, unless you're writing your SQL in code dynamically, there's no compatibility benefit in using the OUTER keyword.

Comment: Right, but no harm, no foul =)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment you want to find any non-matching rows that imported badly. I would first find all the matching rows that imported correctly and then just select anything not present in that set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE code NOT IN (
    -- find all the matching values of code which imported correctly
    SELECT code 
    FROM table1 
      JOIN table2 ON table1.code = table2.code
)
```

This will not be a fast query but since it is for integrity checking it won't need to be run in production after the initial import so speed isn't the main issue.

Comment: Why not a LEFT JOIN on the derived table? That will use the indexes reliably, whereas NOT IN may not (it sometimes does, and sometimes doesn't -- it's not predictable in my experience). Unless the result set needs to be editable, I can't see why the LEFT JOIN wouldn't be superior.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Yes that does sound better, hopefully I managed to give a clear indication of the logic required. Not sure if this has helped them at all.